# Get current project in view hook?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

I'm trying to create my first Redmine plugin. Actually i'm trying to create a form in the issue sidebar (the `view_layouts_base_sidebar` hook) , and i can't find a way to get the current project

To get the current user, we can do this

```
User.current
```

Now, i want to get the project of the current issue, do you know how to get it ? as `Project.current` doesn't exist

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the [relevant documentation](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Hooks#Fundamentals), simply using

```
project = context[:project]
```

should do the trick for you.

I would advise against using `Issue.find(context[:request].params[:id])` as it may yield unwanted results. Since the `view_layouts_base_sidebar` is called in all kinds of contexts, `context[:request].params[:id]` could be a wiki page id, a project id, a tracker id, etc. Simply passing that to `Issue.find()` will find no issue in the best case or a totally unrelated issue in the worst case.

I recommend you read about [Rails routing](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#connecting-urls-to-code), too.

Answer (score -1):

I got it

```
issue = Issue.find(context[:request].params[:id])
project = Project.find(issue.project_id)
```

Comment: While this may work in some circumstances, it is sure to yield unwanted results in most others. See my answer for a better solution.